# Error installing python package from command line

Tags: python

I'm trying to efficiently code quantum mechanical time-evolution which requires me to exponentiate Hamiltonian matrices that are very large but very sparse. To do this, I have been trying to install the expokit python wrapper (https://github.com/weinbe58/expokitpy) but am running into issues. I am on Mac and once I download the files and run `python setup.py install` the terminal runs through an installation process but then returns

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing 
xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing 
xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c -c ./expokit/lapack.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/expokit/lapack.o" failed with exit status
```

This is my first time installing a package not using `pip install` and I can't figure out what's going on here. Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. if anyone knows a better package that I should be using, please let me know too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with python, your xcode not installed properly (or missing permissions or something).

```
xcode-select --install
```

Will probably fix it. For more info, look at [this](https://ma.ttias.be/mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun/) article

Also, why not just use scipy? Scipy provides the same functionality, and will probably work better for you if you're already using numpy/scipy. See [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html)

Comment: Great, thanks! I've managed to install the package now. Actually, I have been using `scipy.sparse.linalg.expm_multiply` so far, but the issue is that for matrices of the size that I am dealing with (e.g. 2178309x2178309 sparse matrix with 36789820 non-zero entries) a single matrix exponential still takes about 10 seconds to compute, and I was hoping to get it down to much faster than this...